# using bbfreeze with a pyopengl application on linux

Tags: python, freeze, pyopengl

I have this pyopengl application and I'm trying to freeze it with bbfreeze. Unfortunately when I run the frozen app it errors with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "__main__.py", line 128, in <module>
  File "__main__client__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "ui.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "OpenGL/GLUT/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "OpenGL/raw/GLUT/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "OpenGL/raw/GLUT/constants.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "OpenGL/platform/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "OpenGL/platform/__init__.py", line 27, in _load
  File "OpenGL/plugins.py", line 14, in load
  File "OpenGL/plugins.py", line 28, in importByName
ImportError: No module named glx
```

Here's the requisite version information:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import OpenGL
>>> OpenGL.__version__
'3.0.1b2'
>>> import bbfreeze
>>> bbfreeze.version
(0, 97, 3)
```

I'm trying to run it on the same machine I'm freezing it on, and the unfrozen app runs fine on that machine.

Has anyone managed to make this work? or perhaps provide some debugging guidance?

Comment: I managed to get cxfreeze to freeze the same app and it produces the same error (albeit formatted differently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly adding "OpenGL.platform.glx" to the list of included modules in the freeze.  I think the bbfreeze option "includes" is what you want.

**Update:**  take a look at the way PyInstaller does it:  http://www.pyinstaller.org/browser/trunk/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-OpenGL.py

You will probably need to add all of these modules to your list of includes.

Comment: I did need the others, except numarrays, I don't seem to have that one. Adding these to the includes has indeed resolved my issue, thanks.

Comment: For the list of OpenGL.arrays.* modules, I use this script: `for f in $(setopt extended_glob;ls $(python3 -c "import OpenGL;print(OpenGL.__path__[0])")/arrays/*.py|grep -v __init__);do m="${f##*/}";echo -n ,OpenGL.arrays."${m%.py*}";done`

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same challenge until I read the documention, which states that:

```
 bbfreeze has been tested with python 2.4, 2.5 and 2.6. bbfreeze will not work with python versions prior to 2.3 as it uses the zipimport feature introduced with python 2.3.
```

So i think the best to do is to use the versions of python mentioned! Hope this helps!